# Gradle: Spring 4 BOM dependencies

Tags: gradle, spring-4

How to add Spring 4 BOM dependencies in Gradle configuration file?

In Maven it could be done as mentioned [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/a_webapp_makeover_with_spring).

Maven equivalent:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin

```
plugins {
   id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.4.1.RELEASE"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Gradle has no analogue of Maven's dependency management. You have to declare suitable versions of the dependencies manually.

Comment: It's easy to do achieve something similar to dependency management. But last time I checked, Gradle didn't support BOMs, and it was necessary to inline the BOM dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this spring gradle plugin

> A Gradle plugin that provides Maven-like dependency management and
>   exclusions

https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are 2.5 choices here.

**Using Gradle's native BOM support**

[As of Gradle 4.6](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import) it [supports](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) BOMs natively. Add these lines in your build files:

*settings.gradle*:

```
enableFeaturePreview('IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT')
```

Starting from Gradle 5.0 it's not needed.

*build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE")

    // Now you can import Spring dependencies without particular version:
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
}
```

**Using Spring Boot Gradle plugin**

> When you apply the [`io.spring.dependency-management`](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) plugin, Spring Boot’s plugin will automatically [import the `spring-boot-dependencies` bom](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins-dependency-management) from the version of Spring Boot that you are using. This provides a similar dependency management experience to the one that’s enjoyed by Maven users. For example, it allows you to omit version numbers when declaring dependencies that are managed in the bom. To make use of this functionality, simply declare dependencies in the usual way but omit the version number.

*build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.3.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
    // Now just import what you need:
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
}
```

**Using `io.spring.dependency-management`**

Nice feature is that [you can use Spring's dependency plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation) even if you're not interested in Spring Boot.

*build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.6.RELEASE")
        mavenBom("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.409") // Import any bom!
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb")
}
```